# rename captains-log exposed methods

Tags: node.js, logging, sails.js

is there a way to change the methods exposed by captains-log?
I'm working on a sailsJs project. I need the log levels and calls to be:
FATAL\ERROR\WARN\INFO\DEBUG
I managed to changed the log levels, by doing this in the config.log file:

```
var winston = require('winston');
winston.setLevels(
  {
    crit: 1,
    error: 2,
    warn: 3,
    info: 4,
    debug: 5,
    verbose: 6
  });

module.exports.log = {
  level: 'info',
  custom: new winston.Logger({
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.Console(),
      new(winston.transports.File)(
      {
        filename: './.tmp/log.log'
      }),
    ]
  })
};
```

but I can't find a way to rename crit, to be fatal, so I can do:
`sails.log.fatal` instead of `sails.log.crit`

thanks!